# Alternative to MSMQ

Tags: message-queue, distributed-computing

I need to write a queuing system and I'd like to know what alternatives are there for queuing messages around Microsoft servers to MSMQ?

I know a little about MS-DTC and BizTalk but what are the pros and cons of these options and am I missing anything?

I need In-Order message delivery and potentially the ability to scale horizontally.

I'm dealing with upto around 100,000 messages an hour of less than 256kb per message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS-DTC has nothing to do with queuing, it is the Distributed Transaction Cordinator, and MSMQ can enlist in a Distributed Transaction to ensure reliable message delivery.

The issue with Biztalk IMHO, is the additional cost and complexity of having to support a biztalk server. If all you want is queuing then Biztalk might be overkill. A big seller of biztalk is the tools it provides for integrating various systems together.

What is wrong with MSMQ? You could easily handle that load, and I believe MSMQ can scale out when running in Active Directory.

You could also look at other vendors IBM's MQ Series (Which I would advise against if your in a microsoft environment), Rhino Queues is another one I am vaguley familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Nothing is particularly wrong with MSMQ, I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ is really good.  Also search for AMQP.  That stands for Advanced Message Queueing Protocol.  It's an open standard for message queues.  RabbitMQ is an implementation of AMQP.